# iOS map kriging (interpolation)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps, kriging

Is there any way (or framework) which will allow me to krig my map. I have a few sensors on my map, each with a value (which is dynamic), and based on that value the surrounding area should be painted with some color. 
I would like the map to look something like this:
[image]

Any help or idea, for any type of kriging, is more than welcomed.